# extract unique value into a file in R

Tags: r

I wish it could output unique values into a file "output.txt", my code

```
sink("output.txt")
d=as.factor(c("a","b","c","c","3.1",3.1))
unique(d)
sink()
```

It output as

```
Levels: a b c 3.1
```

But I wish it as one element in one line like:

```
a
b
c
3.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sink("output.txt")
d=as.factor(c("a","b","c","c"))
d <- unique(as.character(d))
cat(d, sep="\n")
sink()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
sink("output.txt")
d=as.factor(c("a","b","c","c"))
t(t(levels(d)))
sink()
```